# Replace child name by concatenating its parent name, move up at level of parent, and remove the parent element using Ling to Xml

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have this original Xml:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Home>
       <Kitchen>
          <Pantry>
             <Ingredients>
                <Name>Tomato</Name>
                <Price>
                   <ID>1</ID>
                   <Name>SALES</Name>
                </Price>
                <Cost>
                   <ID>2</ID>
                   <Name>COGS</Name>
                </Cost>
              </Ingredients>
           </Pantry>
        </Kitchen>
    </Home>
```

And I want it to look like this, concatenated price/cost-id/name:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Home>
       <Kitchen>
          <Pantry>
             <Ingredients>
                <Name>Tomato</Name>
                <Price_ID>1</Price_ID>
                <Price_Name>SALES</Price_Name>
                <Cost_ID>2</Cost_ID>
                <Cost_Name>COGS</Cost_Name>
              </Ingredients>
           </Pantry>
        </Kitchen>
    </Home>
```

Here's my code so far, and I am getting an error in this line `xChild.ReplaceWith(new XElement(concatName, xChild.Value.ToString()));` -- System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

```cs
    // source programmatically generated
    XElement xml = XElement.Parse(xml.ToString());

    foreach (XElement xParent in xQuery.Descendants("Ingredients").Nodes())
    {
        if (xParent.HasElements)
        {
            string parentName = xParent.Name.ToString();
    
            foreach (XElement xChild in xParent.DescendantsAndSelf(xParent.Name).Nodes())
            {
                string childName = xChild.Name.ToString();
                string concatName = xParent.Name.ToString() + "_" + xChild.Name.ToString();
    
                XElement child = xChild.Element(childName); //looks like this is the culprit
    
                xChild.ReplaceWith(new XElement(concatName, xChild.Value.ToString())); //error here: System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
                XElement concatElement = xChild.Element(concatName);
                xChild.AddBeforeSelf(concatElement); 
            }
    
            foreach (XElement elParent in xQuery.Descendants("Ingredients"))
            {
                if (elParent.Element(parentName) != null)
                {
                    XElement parentEl = xParent.Element(parentName);
                    parentEl.Remove();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try going in reverse. List<XElement> nodes = xQuery.Descendants("Ingredients").Nodes(); for(int i = nodes.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--){ XElement xChild = nodes[i];} You are replacing items that were already replaced and failing.  Starting from end will get rid of error.  Do same for 2nd foreach.

Comment: @jdweng I am not getting it exactly. What do you mean reverse? I tried to replace this `foreach (XElement xParent in xQuery.Descendants("Ingredients").Nodes())` with your suggested code straightforward, and I am getting errors on `xParent - does note exist in the current context` and `XElement - is a type, not valid in a given context`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your primary issue is that your `.Nodes()` list is changing while you are enumerating it. You need to use `.ToList` or `.ToArray` on it.

It feels like you are over-complicating this anyway. You can just remove each child node, rename it, and add back as a sibling of its parent.

```cs
var ingredients = xQuery.Descendants("Ingredients");
foreach (XElement xParent in ingredients.Nodes().ToList())
{
    if (!xParent.HasElements)
    continue;
                
    string parentName = xParent.Name.ToString();

    foreach (XElement xChild in xParent.Nodes().ToArray())
    {
        string concatName = xParent.Name + "_" + xChild.Name;
        xChild.Remove();
        xChild.Name = concatName;
        xParent.AddBeforeSelf(xChild);
    }
    xParent.Remove();
}
```

[**dotnetfiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QkaYZX)

Comment: You're exactly right! I was over-complicating it. I debug each of the line codes and saw that the count of the xChild has changed while doing some changes. Thank you, thank you very much as always.